# Can't run Azure project with StorageClient 1.7.1

Tags: azure, storage, worker

I am attempting to run an Azure solution in VS2012 that contains three projects:

1. InSysDashboard (Web Role)
2. InSysService (Web Role)
3. InSysWatcher (Worker Role)

Before 3. was added, 1. and 2. built and deployed just fine.  3. builds just fine on it's own and deploys OK (but of course this is not good because the Roles can't be deployed separately, and need to be deployed as part of the same package).

The problem seems to be with Azure SDK 1.7.1 Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient which I downloaded and compiled from https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/sdk_1.7.1.  I'm using both the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient and Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration libraries from this resource, and the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics and Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime from the VS2012 1.7 June SDK.

The solution containing all three projects compiles with no error.

There is no explicit reference to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient 1.7 in any of the projects, only 1.7.1.

However, when I try to run the solution the Worker Role (3.) fails to load.  There Output window contains the following snippet:

```
'WaIISHost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll'
'WaIISHost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Entity\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Entity.dll'
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Information: 200 : Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStart()
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Information: 203 : Role entrypoint . CALLING   Run()
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Information: 100 : Role environment . INITIALED RETURNED. HResult=0
'WaIISHost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'F:\Everything\Current_Work\Web_Apps\Azure\InSys\InSysCloud\csx\Debug\roles\InSysService\approot\bin\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.dll'
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Information: 101 : Role environment . INITIALIZED
'WaWorkerHost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'F:\Everything\Current_Work\Web_Apps\Azure\InSys\InSysCloud\csx\Debug\roles\InSysWatcher\approot\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll'
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Information: 202 : Role entrypoint . COMPLETED OnStart()
The thread 'Role Initialization Thread' (0xaa4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Information: 203 : Role entrypoint . CALLING   Run()
'WaWorkerHost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'F:\Everything\Current_Work\Web_Apps\Azure\InSys\InSysCloud\csx\Debug\roles\InSysWatcher\approot\InSysWatcher.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WaWorkerHost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll'
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Critical: 201 : Role entrypoint could not be created:
System.TypeLoadException: Unable to load the role entry point due to the following exceptions:
-- System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient, Version=1.7.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient, Version=1.7.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = BertiesExtreme\bertie
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient, Version=1.7.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///F:/Everything/Current_Work/Web_Apps/Azure/InSys/InSysCloud/csx/Debug/roles/InSysWatcher/approot
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = F:\Everything\Current_Work\Web_Apps\Azure\InSys\InSysCloud\csx\Debug\roles\InSysWatcher\approot
Calling assembly : InSysWatcher, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.


LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: F:\Everything\Current_Work\Web_Apps\Azure\InSys\InSysCloud\csx\Debug\roles\InSysWatcher\approot\InSysWatcher.dll.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///F:/Everything/Current_Work/Web_Apps/Azure/InSys/InSysCloud/csx/Debug/roles/InSysWatcher/approot/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: PUBLIC KEY TOKEN
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.


-- System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient, Version=1.7.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient, Version=1.7.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

The last entry seems to indicate a problem with Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.

If I look inside the CSX folders generated when the solution is built, for each of the projects I find:

1. Release/roles/InSysDashboard/approot/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll (which is 1.7.1)
2. Release/roles/InSysService/approot/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll (which is 1.7.1)
3. Release/roles/InSysWatcher/approot/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll (which is **1.7.0**)

For some reason version 1.7.0 of the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll is being included for the Worker Role.  I've checked the reference list and it definitely includes 1.7.1 NOT 1.7.0, so why is 1.7.0 getting included?  I'm assuming at this stage this is the reason for the Worker Role isn't running.

Any ideas?

SOME MORE INFORMATION:

If I replace the version of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll (1.7.0.0) in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure.NET SDK\2012-06\ref with the 1.7.1.0 version, I then get an error relating to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.

```
{"Could not create Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35."}
```

and then in the inner exception:

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient, Version=1.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient, Version=1.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"}
```

It seems that Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics has a dependency on Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient 1.7.0.0, and so replacing it with 1.7.1.0 causes a problem.  I guess the dependency is hard-coded.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out the systems.diagnostics section of the app.config of the InSysWatcher (Worker Role) seems to have helped, i.e. the solution can now be deployed and seems to be functioning as expected.  The doesn't seem like the 'right' way to do it, but after spending nearly 2 days on it, at this point "whatever works".

Answer (score 0):

entirely frustrating, all I've ever found to work is to clean the solution in VS and try again - sometimes it takes multiple cleans before the solution will run.

It seems the conflict arises at times when another version of the StorageClient is present in the GAC